# Deleting a directory under Windows in a race-free manner?

Tags: winapi, file-io, race-condition

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=365 discusses the potential race-conditions that may occur while deleting a directory recursively.

According to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7148952 this can be implemented in a race-free manner under Linux using [openat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/openat). Is there an equivalent mechanism under Windows?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS might help.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Please post a formal answer so I can comment on it in more detail.

Comment: @Misha: I have no way of knowing. Their documentation doesn't discuss this at all.

Comment: Boost.Filesystem is based on paths, and any path-based API is going to be vulnerable to these races. Transactional NTFS might work, but Microsoft is discouraging its use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A key difference between Windows filesystem behavior and linux filesystem behavior is locking and reference counting.

In Windows if a process has a file open, then that file *and* the path leading to that file are protected.

So, if somebody has "C:\a\b\c\d\file.txt" open, then nobody is allowed to rename or delete any part of the path "C:\a\b\c\d\file.txt".

The linux model is much different, any part of that path can be changed and even the file can be deleted. The process holding the handle to "file.txt" still has a reference, and the file wouldn't be removed from the filesystem until all handles are closed.

The Win32 API doesn't expose a direct way to hold a handle to a directory (though, there are APIs for this - see the "Zw" functions, FindFirstFile may I'm not sure, the backup APIs, etc) - but your process "current directory" does hold a handle for that directory.

Thus, you can get "openat" behavior by changing your working directory and then opening the file directly. Better would be to use something like ZwCreateFile() to open a handle to the directory - since the "current dir" is process global.

Search Stackoverflow and Microsoft.com for ZwCreateFile information.

Comment: Sounds promising. Thanks!